# Setting background image in a repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set a background image in a repeater programmatically. Variations of the following have not worked, including trying to set the url in the `div`, not the jquery function:

The JQuery function:

```
var getBackgroundImage = function (imagePath) {
    var backgroundImage = 'url(' + iipServ + '?FIF=/IIPServer/images/' + imagePath + '&WID=40&CVT=PNG' + ')';
    return backgroundImage;
};
```

The ASP page:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="docResults" runat="server" ItemType="ArchiveViewer.Models.Document" 
     SelectMethod="GetSearchResults" >
     <ItemTemplate> 
         <div class="result" data-docid="<%#:Item.DocumentId %>" 
             data-imageDir="<%#:Item.FolderPath %>" 
             data-objData="<%#:Item.JSONPath %>" 
             style="<%= getBackgroundImage(Item.Pages.First().ImagePath) %> ">  
                  <%#:Item.Metadata.Title %>
         </div>

     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Can this be done? How? 
Thank you!

EDIT: Each `div` has its own image. I'm getting the URL from the server.

EDIT 2: I am not instead of using a jquery function, am using a web method in my code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string getBackgroundImage(string path)
    {
        string iipServer = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iipServer"].ConnectionString;
        string urlString = "background-image : url('" + iipServer + "?FIF=/IIPServer/images/" + 
                path + "&WID=40&CVT=PNG)'";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(urlString);
        return urlString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pid: Your answer is almost correct, but the compiler didn't like it. It helped me figure out how to do it correctly, though. Thank you.

In case it helps someone else, here is how I fixed this issue:

My ASPX page:

```
<ItemTemplate> 
      <div class="result" data-docid="<%#:Item.DocumentId %>" 
          data-imageDir="<%#:Item.FolderPath %>" data-objData="<%#:Item.JSONPath %>"
          style="<%#: getBackgroundImage(Item.Pages.First().ImagePath) %>" >
        <%#:Item.Metadata.Title %>
      </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And my code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string getBackgroundImage(string path)
    {
        string iipServer = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iipServer"].ConnectionString;
        string urlString = @"background-image:url(" 
                + iipServer + "?FIF=/IIPServer/images/" + 
                path + "&WID=40&CVT=PNG)";
        return urlString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ASPX page:

```
style="background-image : <%=getBackgroundImage(Item.Pages.First().ImagePath) %>">
```

In the code behind:

```
public string getBackgroundImage(string iipServ, string path)
{
    return "url('" + iipServ + "?FIF=/IIPServer/images/" + path + "&WID=40&CVT=PNG)'";
}
```

It's not clear what `iipServ` is and where to take it from. Just pass it to the C# function along the path.

You should remove the JS function, this will be all server-side.

Comment: I need every <div> to have it's own image.

Comment: What I have is not compiling. It doesn't recognize "Item". I've updated my question to show more of my code.